# can Execution groups be used to achieve higher priority

Tags: performance, web-services, soap, messagebroker

I have multiple clients(referring to them as channels) accessing a service on a WebSphere message broker.

The service is a likely to be a SOAP based webservice (can possibly be RESTful too).

Prioritizing requests for MQ/JMS can be handled by WMB using the header info (priority).

The SOAP or HTTP Nodes do not seem to have an equivalent property. Wondering how we cna achieve priority for requests from a  specific client channel.

Can I use multiple execution groups(EG) to give higher priortiy for a specific channel. In other words, I am thinking of using EG to give a bigger pipe for a specific channel which should translate to requests being processed faster compared to the other channels.

Thanks

the end points

Answer (score 1):

If you have IIB v9 you can use the "workload management" feature described here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v9r0m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj58250_.htm
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K11mKCHMRxo

The problem with this is that it allows you to cap different classes of messages at max rates, it won't allow you to run low priority work at full speed when there is no high priority work for example.

So a better approach might be to create multiple EGs using the maxThreads property on the EG level HTTP connector and the number of additional instances configured on each flow to give relative priority to the different classes of traffic.